# Converting string to data object with strptime() not working

Tags: python, string, date

How to convert string `'17 Nov 2021'` into data object `"20211117"`?

I've tried:

```
_date=datetime.strptime(_dateAsString, '%Y%m%d')
```

but it does not work :/

Comment: The specifiers in the format string are wrong and it doesn't have the space characters in it. I suggest you reread the documentation for [`strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse to datetime object and then convert back to string with different date format as follows:

```
import datetime
_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("17 Nov 2021", "%d %b %Y").strftime("%Y%m%d")
# Result: '20211117'
```

You can review the available [strftime() and strptime() format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) if it's not clear what the various codes e.g. `%d` and `%b`  represent.